# spawning a child process to call npm-installed command in nodejs causes ENOENT in windows

Tags: node.js, child-process

I've searched a lot but got no correct answer.

Firstly I'm sure the command is usable under command line, here is the output:

```
> lessc
lessc: no input files

usage: lessc [option option=parameter ...] <source> [destination]
```

However when use `child_process.spawn`, I got:

```
> node test.js
Encountered error: { [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn' }
```

I'm sure the `process.env` is given to `spawn`, here is the nodejs code:

```
var build = require('child_process').spawn(
    'lessc',
    [],
    {
        stdio: 'inherit',
        env: process.env
    }
);

build.on(
    'error',
    function (err) {
        console.log('Encountered error:', err);
        process.exit();
    }
);
build.on(
    'close', 
    function (err) {
        console.log('close');
    }
);
```

And weiredly, it only encounter **ENOENT** when the command is installed via `npm install -g`, it works well on for example `dir` or `del` system command

Comment: It works for me on Linux, will test on Windows soon. In the mean time, I suggest you check your PATH: could it be that the `cmd` window sets a path (say in a `.bat` file you're running) that doesn't exist for spawned process? Also, `dir` and `del` are internal `cmd` commands, so that "doesn't count" (the fact that they work). Try running an external `.exe` to see if it works. Finally, You don't need to specify `env: process.env`, that's the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is turns out, the following works:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var b = spawn(
    process.env.comspec,
    ['/c', 'lessc'],
    { stdio: 'inherit' }
);
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly pass `env` as you do, the default is to inherit.

Comment: I've tried not pass `env`, it still fails, it works in OSX and Linux, but fails in Windows cmd

Comment: After tried `process.env.comspec` it works, however I have 2 more question: is it save to use `/c` as first arg on every windows computer? and why `comspec` works but directly spawning fails, is there any different between them (I already noticed `process.env.comspec` is the `cmd` command)?

Comment: Yes, safe. /c means 'run the following command'  it's not a drive lettrr specification.

Comment: And how should I pass parameters to 'lessc'?

Comment: Just pass them after `'lessc'` in the array. Something like: `['/c', 'lessc', 'param1', 'param2']`